# AttributeError: 'FeatureDB' object has no attribute 'strand'

Tags: python, gffutils

It appers when a gene has a negative strand then I need to reverse the sequence. Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
print("1" + '"' + str(fastaIdx) + '"' + '"' + str(mrna_id) + "'" + db.strand())
AttributeError: 'FeatureDB' object has no attribute 'strand'
```

with the following code:

```
import gffutils
import pyfaidx
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

def getPeptideSeq(fastaIDX, db, mrna_id):
    print("Petide Sequence")
    return Seq(getCdsSeq(fastaIDX, db, db[mrna_id]), IUPAC.unambiguous_dna).translate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = gffutils.FeatureDB('annotation.db', keep_order=True)
    fastaIdx = pyfaidx.Fasta('assembly.fasta')
    print("1" + '"' + str(fastaIdx) + '"' + '"' + str(mrna_id) + "'" + db.strand())

        seq = getPeptideSeq(fastaIdx, db, mrna_id)
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Best wishes,

Comment: Presumably the field isn't called strand. Can you just print all the available fields in your `db` object? Also, what input are you giving? Can you provide a minimal, full example that we can try?

Comment: gffutils databases don't typically have a single strand as they contain many features with different strands. It is typically the `Feature` objects within the database that have a `strand` attribute: https://pythonhosted.org/gffutils/autodocs/gffutils.Feature.html. Was it supposed to be `db[mrna_id].strand` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: If something worked, can you please write it up as an accepted answer? This keeps the StackExchange answer-fishing bots happy.